# Network client simulator design

Tags: c++, multithreading, network-programming, boost-asio

I am trying to design a software in c++ that will send request bytes (following a standard **application level** protocol whose fields to be populated will be taken from a text file) using **UDP protocol**.

Now this client must be able to send these requests at very high rate..upto **2000 transactions per second** and should also receive the response if it gets within a specified timeout else don't receive it

I will be using boost library for all the socket things but I am not sure about the design of it for such high speed application :(

I think I have to use a highly multi-threaded application (again Boost will be used). Am I right ? Do I have to create a seperate thread for each request ? But I think only one thread must be waiting to recieve the response else if many threads are waiting for a response how can we distinguish for which threads request we have got the response for !!

Hope that question is clear. I just need some help regarding the design points and suspected problems that I may face.

Comment: I'm not expert in this field, so I won't post an answer, but: no, you don't necessarily need multithreading (though it may be useful), and no, you certainly don't want to create 2000 threads per second. Consider a preforking approach with the number of threads at roughly 2*#CPU cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm halfway through a network client of my own at the moment, so perhaps I can impart some advice and some resources to look at.  There are many more experienced in this area, and hopefully they'll chime in :)

Firstly, you're about boost.  Once you get used to how it all hangs together, [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is a great toolkit for writing network-code.  Essentially, you create an `io_service` and call `run` to execute until all work is complete, or `runOne` to perform a single IO action.  On their own, this isn't that helpful.  The power comes from when you either run `runOne` in it's own loop:

```
boost::asio::io_service myIOService;
while(true)
{
    myIOService.runOne();
}
```

, or run the `run` function on one (or more) threads:

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &myIOService));
```

However, it is worth noting that `run` returns as soon as there is no work to do (so you can say goodbye to that thread).  As I found out here on Stackoverflow, the trick is to ensure it always has something to do.  The solution is in `boost::asio::io_service::work`:

```
boost::asio::io_service::work myWork(myIOService);   // just some abstract "work"
```

The above line ensures your thread won't stop when nothing is going on.  I view is as a means to keep-alive :)

At some point, you're going to want to create a socket and connect it somewhere.  I created a generic Socket class (and derived a text-socket from that to create buffered input).  I also wanted an event-based system that worked very much like C#.  I've outlined this stuff for you, below:

First step, we need a generic way of passing arguments around, hence, `EventArgs`:

**eventArgs.h**

```
 class EventArgs : boost::noncopyable
 {
 private:

 public:
  EventArgs();
  virtual ~EventArgs() = 0;
 }; // eo class EventArgs:
```

Now, we need an event class which people can subscribe/unsubscribe to:

**event.h**

```
// STL
#include <functional>
#include <stack>

// Boost
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

 // class Event
 class Event : boost::noncopyable
 {
 public:
  typedef std::function<void(const EventArgs&)> DelegateType;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<DelegateType> DelegateDecl;

 private:
  boost::mutex m_Mutex;
  typedef std::set<DelegateDecl> DelegateSet;
  typedef std::stack<DelegateDecl> DelegateStack;
  typedef DelegateSet::const_iterator DelegateSet_cit;
  DelegateSet m_Delegates;
  DelegateStack m_ToRemove;

 public:
  Event()
  {
  }; // eo ctor


  Event(Event&& _rhs) : m_Delegates(std::move(_rhs.m_Delegates))
  {
  }; // eo mtor

  ~Event()
  {
  }; // eo dtor

  // static methods
  static DelegateDecl bindDelegate(DelegateType _f)
  {
   DelegateDecl ret(new DelegateType(_f));
   return ret;
  }; // eo bindDelegate

  // methods
  void raise(const EventArgs& _args)
  {
   boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_Mutex);

   // get rid of any we have to remove
   while(m_ToRemove.size())
   {
    m_Delegates.erase(m_Delegates.find(m_ToRemove.top()));
    m_ToRemove.pop();
   };

   if(m_Delegates.size())
   std::for_each(m_Delegates.begin(),
        m_Delegates.end(),
        [&_args](const DelegateDecl& _decl) { (*_decl)(_args); });
  }; // eo raise

  DelegateDecl addListener(DelegateDecl _decl)
  {
   boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_Mutex);
   m_Delegates.insert(_decl);
   return _decl;
  }; // eo addListener

  DelegateDecl addListener(DelegateType _f)
  {
   DelegateDecl ret(bindDelegate(_f));
   return addListener(ret);
  }; // eo addListener


  void removeListener(const DelegateDecl _decl)
  {
   boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_Mutex);
   DelegateSet_cit cit(m_Delegates.find(_decl));
   if(cit != m_Delegates.end())
    m_ToRemove.push(_decl);
  }; // eo removeListener

  // operators

  // Only use operator += if you don't which to manually detach using removeListener
  Event& operator += (DelegateType _f)
  {
   addListener(_f);
   return *this;
  }; // eo op +=

 }; // eo class Event
```

Then, it was time to create a socket class.  Below is the header:

**socket.h**

(Some notes: `ByteVector` is `typedef std::vector<unsigned char>`)

```
#pragma once

#include "event.h"

// boost
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>
  // class Socket
  class MORSE_API Socket : boost::noncopyable
  {
  protected:
   typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> SocketPtr;

  private:
   ByteVector      m_Buffer;   // will be used to read in

   SocketPtr        m_SocketPtr;
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint      m_RemoteEndPoint;
   bool         m_bConnected;

   // reader
   void _handleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& _errorCode, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver_iterator _rit);
   void _handleRead(const boost::system::error_code& _errorCode, std::size_t read);
  protected:

   SocketPtr socket() { return m_SocketPtr; };
  public:
   Socket(ByteVector_sz _bufSize = 512);
   virtual ~Socket();

   // properties
   bool isConnected() const { return m_bConnected; };
   const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& remoteEndPoint() const {return m_RemoteEndPoint; };

   // methods
   void connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver_iterator _rit);
   void connect(const String& _host, const Port _port);
   void close();

   // Events
   Event onRead;
   Event onResolve;
   Event onConnect;
   Event onClose;
  }; // eo class Socket
```

And, now the implementation.  You'll notice it calls another class to perform DNS resolution.  I will show that afterwards.  Also there are some `EventArg`-derivatives I have ommitted.  They are simply passed as EventArg parameters when socket events occur.

**socket.cpp**

```
#include "socket.h"


// boost
#include <boost/asio/placeholders.hpp>

namespace morse
{
 namespace net
 {
  // ctor
  Socket::Socket(ByteVector_sz _bufSize /* = 512 */) : m_bConnected(false)
  {
   m_Buffer.resize(_bufSize);
  }; // eo ctor

  // dtor
  Socket::~Socket()
  {
  }; // eo dtor


  // _handleRead
  void Socket::_handleRead(const boost::system::error_code& _errorCode,
            std::size_t _read)
  {
   if(!_errorCode)
   {
    if(_read)
    {
     onRead.raise(SocketReadEventArgs(*this, m_Buffer, _read));
     // read again
     m_SocketPtr->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_Buffer), boost::bind(&Socket::_handleRead, this, _1, _2));
    };
   }
   else
    close();
  }; // eo _handleRead


  // _handleConnect
  void Socket::_handleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& _errorCode,
         boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver_iterator _rit)
  {
   m_bConnected = !_errorCode;
   bool _raise(false);
   if(!_errorCode)
   {
    m_RemoteEndPoint = *_rit;
    _raise = true;
    m_SocketPtr->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_Buffer), boost::bind(&Socket::_handleRead, this, _1, _2));
   }
   else if(++_rit != boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator())
   {
    m_SocketPtr->close();
    m_SocketPtr->async_connect(*_rit, boost::bind(&Socket::_handleConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, _rit));
   }
   else
    _raise = true; // raise complete failure

   if(_raise)
    onConnect.raise(SocketConnectEventArgs(*this, _errorCode));

  }; // eo _handleConnect


  // connect
  void Socket::connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver_iterator _rit)
  {
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(*_rit);
   m_SocketPtr.reset(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(Root::instance().ioService()));
   m_SocketPtr->async_connect(ep, boost::bind(&Socket::_handleConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, _rit));
  };


  void Socket::connect(const String& _host, Port _port)
  {
   // Anon function for resolution of the host-name and asynchronous calling of the above
   auto anonResolve = [this](const boost::system::error_code& _errorCode, 
           boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver_iterator _epIt)
   {
    // raise event
    onResolve.raise(SocketResolveEventArgs(*this, !_errorCode ? (*_epIt).host_name() : String(""), _errorCode));

    // perform connect, calling back to anonymous function
    if(!_errorCode)
     this->connect(_epIt);
   };

   // Resolve the host calling back to anonymous function
   Root::instance().resolveHost(_host, _port, anonResolve);

  }; // eo connect


  void Socket::close()
  {
   if(m_bConnected)
   {
    onClose.raise(SocketCloseEventArgs(*this));
    m_SocketPtr->close();
    m_bConnected = false;
   };
  } // eo close
```

As I said about DNS resolution, the line `Root::instance().resolveHost(_host, _port, anonResolve);` calls this to perform asynchronous DNS:

```
  // resolve a host asynchronously
  template<typename ResolveHandler>
  void resolveHost(const String& _host, Port _port, ResolveHandler _handler)
  {
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ret;
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(_host, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(_port));
   m_Resolver.async_resolve(query, _handler);
  }; // eo resolveHost
```

Finally, I need a text-based socket that raised an event every time I line was received (which is then processed).  I'll omit the header file this time and just show the implementation file.  Needless to say it declares an `Event` called `onLine` which it fires every time a line is received in it's entirety:

```
// boost
#include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/placeholders.hpp>

namespace morse
{
 namespace net
 {
  String TextSocket::m_DefaultEOL("\r\n");

  // ctor
  TextSocket::TextSocket() : m_EOL(m_DefaultEOL)
  {
   onRead += boost::bind(&TextSocket::readHandler, this, _1);
  }; // eo ctor


  // dtor
  TextSocket::~TextSocket()
  {
  }; // eo dtor


  // readHandler
  void TextSocket::readHandler(const EventArgs& _args)
  {
   auto& args(static_cast<const SocketReadEventArgs&>(_args));
   m_LineBuffer.append(args.buffer().begin(), args.buffer().begin() + args.bytesRead());
   String::size_type pos;
   while((pos = m_LineBuffer.find(eol())) != String::npos)
   {
    onLine.raise(SocketLineEventArgs(*this, m_LineBuffer.substr(0, pos)));
    m_LineBuffer = m_LineBuffer.substr(pos + eol().length());
   };
  }; // eo readHandler


  // writeHandler
  void TextSocket::writeHandler(const boost::system::error_code& _errorCode, std::size_t _written)
  {
   if(!_errorCode)
   {
    m_Queue.pop_front();
    if(!m_Queue.empty()) // more to do?
     boost::asio::async_write(*socket().get(), boost::asio::buffer(m_Queue.front(), m_Queue.front().length()), boost::bind(&TextSocket::writeHandler, this, _1, _2));
   }
   else
    close();
  }; // eo writeHandler

  void TextSocket::sendLine(String _line)
  {
   Root::instance().ioService().post(boost::bind(&TextSocket::_sendLine, this, _line));
  }; // eo sendLine


  // _sendLine
  void TextSocket::_sendLine(String _line)
  {
   // copy'n'queue
   _line.append(m_EOL);
   m_Queue.push_back(_line);
   if(m_Queue.size() == 1) // previously an empty queue, must start write!
    boost::asio::async_write(*socket().get(), boost::asio::buffer(m_Queue.front(), m_Queue.front().length()), boost::bind(&TextSocket::writeHandler, this, _1, _2));
  }; // eo sendLine
```

Some things to note about the class above...  it uses `boost::asio::post` to send lines.  This allows it to all occur on the threads that ASIO manages in a thread-safe way, and allows us to queue up lines to be sent as and when.  This makes it very scalable.

I am sure there are many more questions and maybe my code isn't helpful.  I spent several days piecing it all together and making sense of it, and I doubt it's actually any good.  hopefully some better minds will glance over it and go "HOLY CRAP, THIS

Comment: (ran out of room!)... IS BAD!".  If you have any questions, let me know.  I know some code/definitions are missing but there's limited space :)

Comment: +1 good answer, but this is likely overcomplicated for someone just starting to use Boost.Asio. The OP would be better suited to study the examples included with the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer(though I didnt understand much :P)..from your post looks like boost:asio is the thing I should go for. But, what about sending high number of events per second and waiting for their respective responses. What method you employ or going to employ (threading ?).

Comment: @ArunMu, as small_duck said in his reply, you can start multiple threads (basically, the line in my code that starts a boost thread?  Having more!).  I would start with one thread and see how the performance is, scaling up if needed.  I'd start with one boost thread, posting to a processing thread and see what the throughput was like, perhaps adding another thread and other mechanisms to improve performance.

Comment: @Moo-Juice : Will it be possible for you to give a high level architecture of your Network client ? Just need to know how you have placed the Boost asio api's to construct the application.

Comment: @ArunMu.  I have a root object, called `Root` (surprise!) which acts as both a container for my client classes (which, in turn contain the socket mentioned above).  It also contains the `boost::asio::io_service` instance.  In the constructor, it initializes some work (passing that io-service in to the ctor), and starts a new thread off using the `run` method of `io_service`.  When root has finished constructing, io_service is up and running and due to the addition of the `work`, it's happy to sit there until I give it something more to do.  (more coming).

Comment: @ArunMU, in the destructor of root, I close the io_service down and join the threads `boost::thread::join`.  When one of my client classes is instructed to connect somewhere, it is constructed with the host details.  It constructs the socket, and resolves the host name using the resolver method with callback as mentioned above.  Handlers are attached to the various socket events by the client to report name-resolution, connection status, and when data is ready to be read.  The root object keeps track of all the clients within itself.

Comment: @Moo-Juice : Thanks a lot for your explanation :) .I am starting to get this I guess. Something very similar to Pyhton's Twisted module I think.. Now from what I understood ..when we need to send or read data from the socket it calls the repective handler...But as mentioned by small-duck...for asynchronous communication threading is usually not required..but from you code I see you use thread and mutex (to protect some data) ...can you also brief on that too ?

Comment: @ArunMu, actually i only use the mutex to allow the event handlers to be modified from anywhere (for example, lets say you receive some data and want to add or remove your handler when you get it...  you receive data on the boost thread.. what if the UI thread is adding a handler?).  With actual data sending, I use the `boost::asio::io_service::post` method which ensures that the specified function is called on a thread it made, so no mutexes needed.

Comment: @Moo-Juice:: ohk..getting it now :D. Thanks again for your patience in answering my queries.

Comment: @ArunMu, no problem.  Also, note that my code uses a single thread to do all the network I/O.  In your case, with multiple threads, you will want to look in to using strands on your post/receiving handlers to ensure that a single function call is not accessed by more than one thread at one time.  Once you get your head around all this stuff, it all makes sense, but it is quite daunting at the start, I admit :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice : One last doubt , can i use two different instances of io_service for both sending data to server and receiving data from the server or do I have to use strands only ?

Comment: Also i intend to use two different threads for both send and receive io_services and my main code will join these threads.

Comment: @Arunmu, I'm not sure why you'd throw two different io_service's at that, and not even sure if it would work unless you were using one socket to send and one to receive (as a socket gets bound to an io_service).  As for separate threads for sending/receiving it is my understanding that boost::asio uses the threads as it sees fit, but I MAY BE WRONG on this.  It might be worth checking out the documentation a little more deeply on that fact.  Either way, I am sure you'll get the throughput you need :)

Comment: Yes you are correct, even I doubted it would work. I wanted it because  I wanted to make both send and receive operations completely exclusive to each other.Like just go on sending events(ofcourse making sure server doesnt gets killed :) ) and receive the events as it comes by

Comment: @ArunMu, you'll get that behavior anyway thanks to the asynchronous nature of the beast.  Whether "under the hood" you are receiving at the same time as sending is not really worth worrying about :)

Comment: Yup its working ...asio is really amazing..I can really feel the power :)

Comment: @ArunMu, awesome :)  Happy Asynchronous coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot for introducing me to it and answering my queries

Comment: @ArunMU, anytime.  That's what this site is for! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need to go "heavy" multi-thread. Most high speed applications use the polling mechanisms of the operating system, which generally scale better than threads.

The architecture will depend a lot on how reactive your application needs to be, in terms of what components are responsible for generating inputs and outputs, and doing the actual processing.

A way to approach your problem using boost::asio would be to have a communication thread that runs the boost::asio::io_service::run method. The io_service listens on the various UDP sockets, and processes messages as they arrive, possibly sending them down a queue so that the application can process them in the main thread. From the main thread, you can post messages to the io_services for them to be sent by the main system.

This should allow you to climb up to 2000 messages per seconds without much difficulties.

An alternative would be to start several communication threads by calling the boost::asio::io_service::run method several times from several threads, allowing for messages to be processed in parallel by their communication thread.

One word of advice with Asio, though: because of its asynchronous architecture, it works better if you go within its logic and use it the way it is meant to. If you find out that you are using a lot of locks and managing many threads yourself, then you are probably doing it wrong. Look closely at the thread safety guarantees of the various methods, and study the provided examples.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs . I will try to get the nitty gritty of boost asio . Even I will be happy if I dont need to use threads :).. Do we have any other good source for understanding boost asio other than the standard documentation ?